# AJAX login with Codeigniter, Ion Auth and jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, authentication

I have authentication up and running in CodeIgnitor using Ion Auth, seems to be a great library with all the functionality I need. But I want to create an AJAX login, using jQuery. Basically to enhance the functionality / degrade gracefully when javascript is or is not present.

I have no idea how to do it so that on subsequent pages where Ion Auth checks the logged in status it will all work properly.

Here's what I have so far:

--

#### CONTROLLER

```
public function js_login()
    {

        if( $this->ion_auth->login($this->input->post('identity'),
            $this->input->post('password'), 
            $this->input->post('remember')))
        {
            $result = "Login Details Correct";
        }
        else
        {
            $result = "Login Details incorrect";
        }

        $array = array( "result" => $result );
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
```

--

#### SCRIPT

```
     $("#login").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $.post( "/auth/js_login", $(this).serialize(), function(data){
                // Set the cookie somehow
                alert(data.result);
                }, "json");
        });
```

--

So I basically need to know how to get the session data that is normally set by Ion Auth and set it using jQuery. After that I can redirect to the appropriate page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do the session setting when your login succeeds with PHP (in the js_login function) and just redirect the user. It'll automatically be effective on the next page.

Comment: I don't follow...  If I redirect in the js_login PHP function nothing happens, and this isn't what I want to achieve.

Comment: No, you got me wrong, set the sessions, cookies etc. inside the js_login function. Then return "Login Details Correct" to your script with AJAX then do whatever you want. Sessions or cookies are set at the backend. You can refresh your page, redirect to user profile etc. after you do that.

Comment: Can you post the complete working example to help other users?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember that much about this now, but it's mostly all same in any login scripts. Like here: http://www.phpnerds.com/article/using-cookies-in-php/2